# Does a Debit/ATM card contain the name of the account owner?

Tags: debit-card, atm

Does a bank or ATM have access to the identity of the person withdrawing cash through a Debit/ATM card issued by another bank as part of the transaction ?

Comment: To be clear, the _account owner_ is on the card, and all the card issuers (banks etc) will always tell you not to let anyone else use your card, but nevertheless people do and so the person _using_ the card may be different from the person _on_ the card.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 actually, for authorized users - it's the authorized user's name that's on the card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name is encoded in the magnetic stripe (and the chip) of any financial card, as per [ISO 7813](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7813).